# Angular leaflet directive zoom to marker on the center of the map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zooming, markers, angular-leaflet-directive

Dear fellow programmers,

I try to create a map with leaflet directive. You can see the fiddle here.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9v3osoxa/)
In the fiddle above, when i drag the map, the marker will always be in the center. But when i zoom in/out (using the scroll), the map is zooming to the area of my mouse, thus changing the coordinate of my marker.

What should i do to make the map zoom to my marker in the center of the map (and not changing the marker coordinate) when I zoom in/out?

Any help is appreciated :)

This is the js code:

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', 'leafletData', function($scope, leafletData) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    center: {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 5
    },
    markers: {
      marker: {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09,
        draggable: false
      }
    },
    defaults: {
      zoomControl: false
    }
  })

  $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.move', function(event, args) {
    var map = args.leafletEvent.target;
    var center = map.getCenter();

    // Update the marker.
    $scope.markers = {
      marker: {
        draggable: false,
        lat: center.lat,
        lng: center.lng,
        draggable: false
      }
    };
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as a start [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrd80vb/):

```
var app = angular.module('demoapp', ['leaflet-directive']);

app.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'leafletData', function($scope, $timeout, leafletData) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    center: {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 5
    },
    markers: {
      marker: {
        lat: 51.505,
        lng: -0.09,
        draggable: false
      }
    },
    defaults: {
      dragging: false,
      scrollWheelZoom: false
    }
  });
}]);
```

And in your html be sure to pass the defaults:

```
<body ng-controller="DemoController">
  <leaflet defaults="defaults" center="center" markers="markers" defaults="defaults"></leaflet>
</body>
```

Now users can not zoom and drag with the mouse, only using the zoom controls which makes the map stay centered.

In the leaflet docs [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options) they say, you can set `scrollWheelZoom` to `'center'`, that would always zoom to the current center of the map (that should be what you want), but i could not get this to work on plunkr. Not sure why, maybe angular-leaflet is not supporting this feature?!

Comment: Thanks. setting scrollWheelZoom to 'center' is exactly what i need. I tested it on my app and it works. Not sure why it's not working on plunkr/jsfiddle though..